# Loading http page in an iframe of https page

Tags: php, iframe, https

I have a page in a https site say `https://www.example.com` which contains an iframe that points to another php page `target.php` in same site .

```
<iframe src="/target.php"></iframe>
```

This target.php is redirecting the request to another **http** url using

```
header("Location: http://demosite/page"  ,TRUE, 307)
```

Unfortunately , this redirection to http site is not working from the https iframe . Although it works from iframe in http page .

I have tried

```
file_get_contents("http://demosite/page")
```

and curl in `target.php` (instead of header redirection) . Those did not return the page in proper format .

Please can someone advise me how to display a http page in an iframe of https page.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the protocol in the redirection. Then it will automatically use the same protocol that was used to access `target.php`:

```
header("Location: //demosite/page", true, 307);
```

Comment: Sorry , this did not work . This php page is in https site . The demosite is a http page . It can not provide secure connection . So the https link to "https://demosite/page" always failed